# Delete rows from mysql server from a list of ID's C#

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I'm trying to delete a series of rows in a MySQL table from a list of ID's in C#. There's an employeeID row in the table. Basically my question is what kind of syntax would I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably use an `IN` clause in your `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM `EmployeeTable` WHERE EmployeeID IN (2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

This could be implemented with the `String.Join` method to generate the list:

```
var query = "DELETE FROM `EmployeeTable` WHERE EmployeeID IN (" +
    String.Join(",", myArray) + ")";
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the IN clause, but I'm using a list rather than an array. It's not working when I use myList.ToString().

Comment: Try `String.Join(",", myList.ToArray())`

Comment: Huh. Apparently it's not a list now that I look at it. It's a DataGridRowViewSelectedRowCollection. I'm using a datagridrowview to display the contents of the MySQL table. How would it work with that?

Comment: You may just have to loop through them and populate a list/array yourself.  Not sure how to get the ID from that, may have to reference docs.

Comment: It will allow me once I have the index, like say if I were to use a for loop, but that's not possible in a string. Would it just be more efficient to do a foreach statement and make separate queries?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Dapper it would look something like this:

```
int[] ids = new int[]{1,2,3};
DbConnection cn = ... //open connection here
cn.Execute("delete from Employee where employeeID in @ids", new {ids});
```

Comment: I'm using .NET connector, can you accommodate your code accordingly?

Answer (score -1):

delete from employee where employeeId in( 2,4,3,2,34 )

Comment: I'm using a list instead of those numbers