# Delete a List<T> using Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Using Dapper or [Dapper.SimpleCRUD](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD), How might I delete a List from a table.  Something like:

```
    public static void DeleteList<T>(List<T> listToDelete)
    {
        using (var connection = OpenConnection())
        {
            connection.Delete<T>(listToDelete);
        }
    }
```

But when I try that, I get...

> The member of type DataModel.MyTable cannot be used as a parameter value

Is the only option to pass in a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any Dapper method for what you want to achieve. The only options are two single deletes and two multiple deletes.

```
public static int Delete<T>(this IDbConnection connection, int Id)

public static int Delete<T>(this IDbConnection connection, T entityToDelete)

public static int DeleteList<T>(this IDbConnection connection, object whereConditions, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)

public static int DeleteList<T>(this IDbConnection connection, string conditions, object parameters = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
```

Both multiple deletes require you to pass conditions or a where clause. Examples:

```
connection.DeleteList<User>(new { Age = 10 });
connection.DeleteList<User>("Where age > 20");
connection.DeleteList<User>("Where age > @Age", new {Age = 20});
```

Comment: ok, yeah, that's what I was seeing too.  Just hoping someone knew a trick I may have missed (or something)

Answer (score 9):

Dapper doesn't know your entity; it is not like Entity Framework. You need to execute a SQL Command or a Store Procedure by yourself.

```
public static void DeleteList(List<int> idToDelete)
{
    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        foreach (int id in idToDelete)
        {
            conn.Execute(@"DELETE FROM [User] WHERE Id = @Id", new {Id = id});
        }
    }
}
```

Or [Execute a Command multiple times](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#execute-a-command-multiple-times)

```
public static void DeleteList(List<int> idToDelete)
{
    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        conn.Execute(@"DELETE FROM [User] WHERE Id = @Id",
            idToDelete.Select(x => new { Id = x }).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Easy way:

```
public void BulkDelete(IEnumerable<int> idList)
    {
        using (var connection = GetNewConnection())
        {
            connection.Execute("Delete FROM MY_TABLE WHERE Id in @idList", new { idList });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the above answer was selected. But Dapper out of the box does not support list functions. Instead of recreating the wheel in my answer see: [Delete rows from mysql server from a list of ID's C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239328/delete-rows-from-mysql-server-from-a-list-of-ids-c-sharp)... just my 2c.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `Dapper.Contrib.Extensions` package, one could use `db.Delete(user);` as long as you're trying to delete by the `Primary Key` (indicated by the `[Key]` annotation on the User object). As soon as you want to delete by anything else, you're better off using `db.Execute(query, params);`.

[Dapper.Contrib.Extension Delete documentation](https://riptutorial.com/dapper-contrib/learn/100006/delete-data)